# How to pass a variable name called "customer_id" through paypal page?

Tags: php, xcode, paypal

**How to pass a variable  call customer_id through paypal page?**

i have a page to pay via Paypal. Everything is saving fine via IPN only the customer_id are not save in db.

The problem i face here is the following.

- after complete payment the variable customer_id did not pass back.
- customer_id was not store in the db.
- i tried session, normal post and hidden but all did not work.

Please HELP!!!!

Comment: `customer_id` is not a valid IPN variable, do you have any documentation supporting the usage of this variable or do you mean `payer_id`?

Answer (score 1):

customer_id is not a parameter that PayPal provides.  You have a couple of options for how you can handle this.

1)  Use the "custom" parameter.  It's actually called custom, and you can pass any value you want up to 256 characters in this field.  If the customer ID is all you need you could include it here and it would come back in the IPN in the custom field as well, but of course you would know that is your customer ID value.

2)  Save the order details in your database prior to generating the button code or API request.  This way you can include the invoice ID in the "invoice" parameter of the request, which would then relate back to your customer record in your database (assuming you have a typical related DB system with customers and orders tables related by a customer ID.)

Then within your IPN script you can grab the invoice ID from the invoice parameter and hit your DB to pull out the related customer ID and do what you need with it.